# Django - How do you email a completed create view form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working on a property management app where users can fill out an online application for a property.  I want to set it up so when someone fills out an application the form gets emailed to the admin formatted with the form labels. Is there a way to email an entire formatted form with labels or am I going to have to make an email template and tag it according to how I want it to look?

My example code:

```
class ApplicationView(CreateView):
    redirect_field_name = ''
    form_class = ApplicantForm
    model = Applicant
    template_name = 'base/application.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        subject = 'New Application - {} {}'.format(
            form.cleaned_data.get('first_name'),
            form.cleaned_data.get('last_name'),
        )
        message = '{} {}'.format(
            form.cleaned_data.get('first_name'),
            form.cleaned_data.get('last_name'),
        )
        Application_Alert(subject, message)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need 2 steps:

- In your `settings.py`, add your email information:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@mail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

- In your `views.py`, import your setting:

```
from django.conf import settings as my_settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

def your_def(request):
    subject = f"{request.user} send subject"
    from_email = my_settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    to_email = ['admin@gmail.com', 'admin2@gmail.com'...] 
    text_content = 'This is an important message.'
    # Add your email template here
    html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, to_email)
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

You can see document at [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types).

Comment: would the def your_def be the def form_valid?  If not how would I call that function from my class-based view?  Is this a better method than calling a separate send email file?  I have a python script where I use a send email function.  I just copied that to this project and it has all the mail settings.

Comment: @Mwheeler91: the def `your_def(request)` is a def in your `views.py` where you can get the front end data, process it and show result to front end. But if you have a python script with all the mail settings, you can try use it.

Answer (score 0):

With emails, you have two options: a text based and a HTML based email. So, if you want a email formatted with labels and nicer looking format, you have to opt for HTML based option. As mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#send-mail).

The fastest approach is to create a `templates/generic/_email.html` and render it bypassing the context variable as you would in a ListView.